# instagram api getting access tokens with permissions and scope not working as expected

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I think i am a bit confused, i need Instagram token to upload images and videos. While trying it from https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/
I had to provide permissions publish_video,pages_show_list,instagram_basic,instagram_content_publish,pages_read_engagement,public_profile, attached in the screen shot below

[image]

Now what i am doing is trying to get access via code in my app, but i guess the permissions in the above screen shot and the scope in the below urls are not the same. What i want to know is how to get valid token to upload imagess and token. any help would be greatly appreciated

Works:

```
https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?
client_id={client_id}&
redirect_uri={url}&
response_type=code&
scope=user_profile,user_media
```

Does not work:

```
https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?
client_id={client_id}&
redirect_uri={url}&
response_type=code&  
scope=user_profile,user_media,publish_video,pages_show_list,instagram_basic,
instagram_content_publish,pages_read_engagement
```

Comment: For future reference the problem appears to be that "user_profile" and "user_media" are scopes for the Instagram Basic Display API, while the other scopes (for publishing, etc) are for the Instagram Graph API.  Facebook really made this so freaking stupid/confusing.

Comment: @SunilD. what exactly should I do to have the Instagram_content_publish permission?